# Series expansion for $x_n=x_{n-1}+\log \left(x_{n-1}\right)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

$x_0=2,\ x_n=x_{n-1}+\log \left(x_{n-1}\right)\quad$ has a series expansion about $1.$

Since $x_0=2,$ $(x_0-1)^k=1,$ so the recurrence can be written, up to the first $5$ terms as

\begin{align}
1+\frac{773788}{604800}\ 2^n-\frac{247200}{604800}\ 2^{2 n}+\frac{118825}{604800}\ 2^{3 n}-\frac{54300}{604800}\ 2^{4 n}+\frac{13687}{604800}\ 2^{5 n}-\dots
\end{align}

found with

```
Evaluate[Plus @@ (((FindSequenceFunction[With[{nn = #}, (Rest@(List @@ 
Series[Nest[# + Log[#] &, x, #], {x, 1, 20}] & /@ Range[0, 20]))
[[All, 3, nn + 1]]]] & /@ Range[0, 5] /. # -> n)[[All, 1]]))]
```

and then combining like terms. The problem is finding the limits of the coefficients of $2^{k n}.$ Theoretically, the recurrence relation should be rewriteable as $$1+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{k+1} c_k 2^{k n}$$

but I don't know how to go about finding a general solution for $c_k.$

## Added

Building on @AntonioVargas' comment below, the recurrence relation seems very close numerically to $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{k+1} \left(n c_k \log (n)-\frac{1}{2} n \log \left(c_k\right)\right)\approx \pi n/2 +n \log n$$

(based on the first $9$ terms of the series expansion).

Numerically, an approximation of the coefficients can be found with something like

```
Abs[With[{aa = SplitBy[SortBy[Flatten@Join[{1, 2^n}, Drop[List @@@ 
Expand[Evaluate[(((FindSequenceFunction[With[{nn = #}, (Rest@(List @@ 
Series[Nest[# + Log[#] &, x, #], {x, 1, 20(*LARGER THAN number of terms*)}] 
& /@ Range[0,20(*LARGER THAN number of terms*)]))[[All, 3, nn + 1]]]] & /@ 
Range[0, 9(*number of terms*)] /. # -> n)[[All, 1]]))]], 2]],  
Coefficient[PowerExpand[Log2[#]], n] &], Coefficient[PowerExpand[Log2[#]], 
n] &]}, (a /. Solve[Plus @@ (aa[[#]]) == a 2^( (# - 1) n), a][[1]] // N) & 
/@ Range[2, Length@aa]]]
```

Comment: I doubt it.  Any random recurrence you write is unlikely to have a closed-form solution.  Only those with a very special form will have a simple formula.

Comment: @JairTaylor yes, that was what I thought :(

Comment: @JairTaylor how about a series expansion?

Comment: For clarity, are we talking about common log or natural log?

Comment: @SeanHenderson natural $\log$

Comment: @martin - in retrospect, it doesn't actually matter all that much.

Comment: @martin Hmm, don't know.  I suppose it's possible there's some brilliant Ramanujan-esque series solution for the sequence :)

Comment: @JairTaylor any Ramanujans out there?!!!

Comment: I'm actually experimenting with [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) because with finite n it can be viewed as a composition series of the series produced by $log(x)+x$

Comment: Even if it did hypothetically have a nonrecursive form, that form probably wouldn't be useful at all.

Comment: @DanielV I agree that it would have to have a rediculous number of terms to approach anything of any "use", but as a mental exercise, I find it quite interesting.

Comment: Series in powers of $x_0-1$, for each fixed $n$?

Comment: @Did setting $x_0=\pi/2$ agrees with setting $x_0=2$ for recurrence. I am aware that this is an anomoly, but unsure how to pose it.

Comment: @Did, would posting a plot help to clarify where my error in explanation is?

Comment: Not really, but explaining what it is you are asking, definitely would.

Comment: @Did I am doing my best!!! Do you have any suggestions, or specific questions that I could answer hopefully more eloquently that I currently am?

Comment: I understand that you are asking for coefficients $c^n_k$ such that, for every $n\geqslant0$, if $x_0=x$ is close enough to $1$ and if $x_i=x_{i-1}+\ln x_{î-1}$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, then $x_n=\sum\limits_kc^n_k\cdot(x-1)^k$. Right?

Comment: @Did yes, I believe that is right.

Comment: Thus, rephrase the question?

Comment: Numerically the asymptotic series for large $n$ appears to be something like $an\log n + bn + c + \cdots$

Comment: @AntonioVargas great - that gives me something to work with - thanks :)

Comment: Based on some further analysis I would guess that $x_n = an\log n + (-a+\log a)n + o(n)$.  Numerics based on this indicate something like $a \approx 1.25$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas great :)  If you get any further with this, and if you have time, please do post an answer. Meanwhile, I will pursue with your observations in mind :)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this question is asking. Where do those power of $2$ come from ???? and how did you obtain those coefficients ? ( I can't read whatever code that is)

Comment: @Histograms - have only just seen your comment - I think 2 must've come at the same time & I missed it! Than ks for the link re Faà di Bruno's formula - have you managed to get anywhere with it so far?

Comment: @mercio code is _Mathematica_ & utilises `Series` and `FindSequenceFunction` (although the first few are guessable of course) as its basic functions. Since the series expands as \begin{align} \\ &1\quad +\\ \\ &\left(2\cdot 2^{n-1}\right)(x_0-1)\quad +\\ \\ &\left(2^{n-2}-2^{2 n-2}\right)(x_0-1)^2\quad +\\ \\ &\left(\frac{2}{9}\ 2^{n-3}-\frac{9}{9}\ 2^{2 n-3}+\frac{7}{9}\ 2^{3 n-3}\right)(x_0-1)^3\quad +\\ \\ &\left(\frac{6}{252}\ 2^{n-4}-\frac{119}{252}\ 2^{2 n-4}+\frac{294}{252}\ 2^{3 n-4}-\frac{181}{252}\ 2^{4 n-4}\right)(x_0-1)^4\quad +\\ \\ &\dots \\ \end{align}

Comment: @merci *continued ...* it is possible to eliminate the $(x_0−1)k=1$ since $x_0=2.$ The rest is combining like terms (since $2^{n-1},2^{n-2},2^{n-3},$ etc. are all expressible as $a 2^{n}$ ). This is actually based on an observation Histograms made [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83468/computing-large-nested-values?noredirect=1#comment225675_83468), and in the comment immediately preceding it.

Comment: @mercio *continued ...* Numerically, the coefficients approximate something like $\small{1.27941, 0.40922, 0.20359, 0.12001, 0.07558, 0.04616, 0.02606, 0.01575\dots},$ based on the first $11$ terms (error of course increasing with term number).

Comment: @martin no unfortunately it's pretty messy. The only other interesting thing I noticed was that you can "reverse" the nest from a given starting point `y0` with `Nest[ProductLog[Exp[#]] &, y0, n]` where `ProductLog` is the Lambert-W function, for instance `Nest[ProductLog[Exp[#]] &, 8.481100676447268`, 5]` gets you back to a starting point of 2.

Comment: @Histograms yes, I have been playing around with the product log too. Nice observation, though agreed, it is pretty messy - there seems be a strange behaviour in terms of convergence to a limit, as it fluctuates.

Comment: why do you think the sum $2/2 + 1/4 + 2/(9*3) + 6/(252*16) + ...$ converges ? it looks like the sequence is slowly converging to $0$ but it seems like an accident to me.

Comment: @Mercio - I am more & more inclined to agree.